# How to generate a report having a pie chart in python?

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm using [ReportLab](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/) for generating reports in PDF. I'm able to get a pdf havinf only textual content in it, but I want to represent the information in the form of a pie chart.

Here is the information that I want to represent on the pie chart.

`[[New Delhi,110kWh],[Bangalore,200kWh]`

ie a pir should have regions of New Delhi and Bangalore with their respective values in percentage.

How can I bring a pie chart into the PDF for generation of reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib to generate a pie chart. See the example [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html).

Save the chart as a image file and place it in your PDF.

Comment: Can you please check why this error is coming? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213339/reportlabs-django-integration

Comment: Please reply to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343382/pyrhon-reportlabs-save-2-different-graphs-in-2-different-pages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tutorial for creating pie-chart using ReportLab : http://www.reportlab.com/snippets/2/

For other types of scientific or data visualizations matplotlib is also good.

Comment: I'm getting this error. Can you please check? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213339/reportlabs-django-integration

Comment: Please reply to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343382/pyrhon-reportlabs-save-2-different-graphs-in-2-different-pages. Thanks