# ReportLabs Django Integration

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm following [this link](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Charts) to integrate the ReportLabs in Django. I did everything correctly but I get an error saying -

```
Exception Type: RenderPMError

Exception Value:    
Can't setFont(Times-Roman) missing the T1 files?
Originally <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: makeT1Font() argument 2 must be string, not None
```

Where I'm going wrong? I guess the font is not available in ReportLabs package. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

To register a font:

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics  
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Arial", os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, 'static', 'fonts', 'arial.ttf'))) # here i have my fonts for PDF's
```

to use it, ex:

```
page = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=A4, pageCompression = 0)

canvas.setFont('Arial',9)
```

Comment: What is `TTFont`.? It throws an error saying `global name 'TTFont' is not defined`

Comment: I downloaded TTFont from http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/. Installed it. But still getting the same error.

Comment: `from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont`

Comment: Please reply to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343382/pyrhon-reportlabs-save-2-different-graphs-in-2-different-pages. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the fonts and place them in your ReportLabs package.

You need these files:

http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/fonts/pfbfer.zip

Unzip them in:

```
/path/to/your/python/site-packages/reportlab/fonts
```

Comment: check again, link was broken.

Comment: Hello Jay, I went to `/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab`. There was no folder `fonts` so I created a folder `fonts` and inside it unzipped the `pfbfer.zip`. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Please reply to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343382/pyrhon-reportlabs-save-2-different-graphs-in-2-different-pages. Thanks

Comment: This works with python3>